# GraphQL APIs in Azure API Management - SQL Database Resolver is not working

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management

I am currently trying to use the SQL Database Resolver for GraphQL API in Azure API Management.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/api-management/sql-data-source-policy

I have defined the following schema and resolver.

Schema

```
type Query {
  getUsers: UserList!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  age: Int!
}

type UserList {
  items: [User!]!
}
```

Resolver

```xml
<sql-data-source>
    <connection-info>
        <connection-string use-managed-identity="true">
            Server=tcp:my-sqlserver.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=my-sqldb;
        </connection-string>
    </connection-info>
    <request>
        <sql-statement>
            SELECT
                u.id
                u.name
                u.age
            FROM
                users u
        </sql-statement>
    </request>
    <response />
</sql-data-source>
```

When I run the test, the following response is returned.

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error trying to resolve field 'getUsers'.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getUsers"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "FILE_NOT_FOUND",
        "codes": [
          "FILE_NOT_FOUND"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

The following error message was output in the trace information.

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Do you know the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the prior answer unfortunately deleted by @dharma there was three things here
(1) commas required in the tsql statement

```html
       <sql-statement>
            SELECT
                u.id,
                u.name,
                u.age
            FROM
                users u
        </sql-statement>
```

(2) the schema was slightly wrong, below is correct

```js
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  age: Int!
}

type UserQueryResult {
  items: [User]  
}

type Query {
  getUsers: UserQueryResult 
}
```

(3)
There was an underlying issue which has been identified and will be resolved. I'll post an update when that work is completed